# Blocked update on lazy loaded nested route

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I use a nested react-router for an admin section to avoid the admin section from loading when people are interacting with the "regular" frontend.

```
<Switch>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      component={() => (
        <HomeRoute
          goApiId={goApiId}
          fbAppId={fbAppId}
          juicerId={juicerId}
          s3Url={s3Url}
          url={url}
        />
      )}
    />


    <Route
      path="/admin"
      render={props => {
        const AdminRoutes = require('./AdminRoutes').default;
        return <AdminRoutes {...props} />;
      }}
    />
[...]
</Switch>
```

The admin section itself also contains a `Switch` statement.

```
const AdminRoutes = () => (
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute
    path="/admin/videos"
    component={AdminVideosRoute}
    key="route-videos"
    />
    <PrivateRoute
    exact
    path="/admin"
    component={AdminHomeRoute}
    key="route-home"
    />
</Switch>
);
```

All navigation on non admin route works fine. However, when I navigate within the admin, nothing happens even though the location changes. This looks like a blocked update.

All the Route components use `withRouter` as top method for the export, identical to the non admin front end.

Any suggestions how to eliminate this problem?

Comment: I ran into the same issue, did you find anything about this in the meantime?